# Virtual Keyboard in Universal App using monogame

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, monogame

Someone know how it is possible to Show and Hide Virtual Keyboard using Monogame in Universal App?
Thanks for help

Comment: Are you looking for Guide.BeginShowKeyboardInput? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamerservices.guide.beginshowkeyboardinput.aspx

Comment: Can the method Guide.BeginShowKeyboardInput be used in Universal App too?i used this in my win8 app and it works fine, but in Universal App i have some trouble...